# ADB WiFi stops after unplug phone (10061)

Tags: android, mobile, adb

Firstly I want tell that **I tried all methods from internet on 3 phones**, works on 2 others (including Huawei p9 with emui 4) but not on Honor 8 with **Android 7.0** (**EMUI 5.0**).

That's what have I done.

```
 1. adb kill-server
 2. adb tcpip <port> (i have used 5555 and others)
 3. adb connect <device_ip>:<port>
 4. "connected to <device_ip>:<port>"
 5. unplug device
 6. no devices on list
```

btw: I can debug via usb cabel but I want to do it over WiFi, someone know solution of this problem?

ps1: please dont tell me about wrong ip or other things like that, I tested it for hundreds of times also my devices have static ip (for a while I test other configuration of it)
ps2: Yes they are on same wifi network

[Screen from command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Mi5i.png)